# Is there a way to make webview show flash content?

Tags: java, android, flash

I am using `webview` to create an Android app that navigates to my website but some of the content of the website is in flash. Is there anyway to make `webview` show flash videos?

I have tried adding the line `myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);` to my `MainActivity.java` , and adding  `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`  to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I was expecting to have my app with `webview` to play flash videos.

Comment: What error you get while doing this?

Answer (score -2):

Can't be done. Adobe Flash Player hasn't been supported on Android since version 11.1.

Comment: But rzwitserloot there are android browsers like Dolphin that support flash.

Comment: @JoaquimChigogoroMussassaJun WebView is based on Chromium, so it has pretty much the same features as the mobile version of Chrome. It's missing a few, but certainly does not have any extra features like flash support. Dolphin is based on WebKit.

Comment: "Can't be done" is completely wrong. Purely technically, you could write your own flash plugin *from scratch*, making it *possible*. *Easy*, however, is a separate issue